# How to search for the newest files in a Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, search, file-sharing

I am running a few file folders for a project in Google Drive. Quite often, collaborators upload or update files in one of the folders.

Is there a way to see the latest changes to the drive, so I can quickly respond to the newly-uploaded files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a sort button on the top right corner. If u want to see changes, click on the details button. I believe it looks like a circle with the letter "i" on the inside. This will show you a short timeline on the right-hand side of the page.

---

*Transferred from edit by OP to their Q:*

> Thanks, [@aurora-afable](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/91643/aurora-afable1), this works pretty well:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW55c.png): 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW55c.png]